# How to get contact list from yahoo in rails using OAuth

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, oauth, yahoo, hotmail

I can successfully get the contacts from google using OAuth gem in rails. my gmail configuration is :

```
:google=>{
    :key=>"***",
    :secret=>"***",
    :expose => true, 
    :scope=>"https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/" 
  }
```

now i want to get contact from yahoo and hot mail. How to get that contact I have given following configuration in my oauth_consumer.rb file

```
:yahoo=>{
   :client=>:oauth_gem, 
   :expose => true, 
   :allow_login => true, 
   :key=>"**",
   :secret=>"**",
   :scope=>"https://me.yahoo.com"
 }

:hotmail=>{
   :client=>:oauth_gem, 
   :expose => true, 
   :allow_login => true, 
   :key=>"**",
   :secret=>"**"  
 }
```

when i am trying to do same like what is done in google it gives error `like undefined method`downcase' for nil:NilClass`

I have also tried [contacts](http://rubygems.org/gems/contacts) gem but fail to load contacts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to use OmniContacts https://github.com/Diego81/omnicontacts this will help you alot.

1. In your gemfile

   ```
   gem "omnicontacts"
   ```
2. Create config/initializers/omnicontacts.rb

   ```
   require "omnicontacts"

   Rails.application.middleware.use OmniContacts::Builder do
     importer :gmail, "client_id", "client_secret", {:redirect_path => "/oauth2callback", :ssl_ca_file => "/etc/ssl/certs/curl-ca-bundle.crt"}
     importer :yahoo, "consumer_id", "consumer_secret", {:callback_path => '/callback'}
     importer :hotmail, "client_id", "client_secret"
     importer :facebook, "client_id", "client_secret"
   end
   ```
3. Create an app to yahoo https://developer.apps.yahoo.com/projects

   This will ask to verify your domain. So, just change your domain of `localhost:3000` to `local.appname.com:3000` or prefer your live server... (change host in local --- sudo gedit /etc/hosts)
4. in your controller

   ```
     @contacts = request.env['omnicontacts.contacts']
     @user = request.env['omnicontacts.user']
     puts "List of contacts of #{user[:name]} obtained from #{params[:importer]}:"
     @contacts.each do |contact|
       puts "Contact found: name => #{contact[:name]}, email => #{contact[:email]}"
     end
   ```

Comment: Thank you nit, I have tried with the same. I forget to write answer for my own question. But I have uploaded the repo which shows the demo of omnicontact. Hopefully all was running but can't be sure for hotmail. https://github.com/sonianand11/omnicontacts_example